# RecyclerView Change ImageView in a certain position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am building a memory game with RecyclerView grid layout. When user clicks 2 time and didn't find the matched pictures, I want to change image view resource only in the clicked positions.
I built the logic sucessfully, but I don't know how to change imageview's resource in only certain positions.

[image]

Comment: Add more information on your logic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with `recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)`

Answer (score 0):

You might have used the OnClickListener interface for card items click events.

So on click event, get the `position` of that clicked image tile using the `getLayoutPosition()` method and change its `Drawable` resource programmaticaLly through captured tile position.

Comment: But how can I only change the imageview resource in a specific position. For example user first 2 match pair is wrong and if user press 3th time the first two pair's imageview must be reset,back to default

Comment: You can save those positions using SharedPreferences and if the two images on those positions don't match, get positions from SharedPreferences that you saved and then change the images.